# To build a flow using Power Automate to download linked csv report in gmail

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to **create a flow using Power Automate** (which I'm quite new to) **that can get the link/URL in an email I receive daily, then download the .csv file that normally a click to the link would do, and then save the file to a given local folder**.

An **example of the email** I get:
[Screenshot of the email I get daily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuveg.jpg)

I searched in Power Automate Community and found **this insightful [LINK](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Building-flow-to-download-link-to-csv-report-in-a-Gmail/td-p/296482) post & answer almost solved it**. However, after following the steps and built the flow, **it kept failing at the Compose step**.

**Screenshot of the Flow & Error Message**
[The flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFBhI.png)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxUw2.png)

**Expression used**:
substring(body('Html_to_text'),add(indexOf(body('Html_to_text'),'here'),5),sub(indexOf(body('Html_to_text'),'Name'),5))

Seems the expression couldn't really get the URL/Link? I'm not sure and searched but couldn't find any more posts that can help.

Please kindly share all insights on approaches or workarounds that you think may help me solve the problem and truly thanks!

PPPPPPPPisces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to breakdown the bits of the function here which needs 3 bits of info

substring(1 text to  search, 2 starting position of the text you want, 3 length of text)

For example, if you were trying to return an unknown number from the text `dog 4567 bird`

Our function would have 3 parts.

1. `body('Html_to_text'),` this bit gets the text we are searching for
2. `add(indexOf(body('Html_to_text'),'dog'),4),` this bit finds the position in the text 4 characters after the start of the word dog (3 letters for dog + the space)
3. `sub(sub(indexOf(body('Html_to_text'),'bird'),2)),add(indexOf(body('Html_to_text'),'dog'),4)),` I've changed the structure of your code here because this part needs to return the length of the URL, not the ending position. So here, we take the position of the end of the URL (position of the word bird minus two spaces) and subtract it from the position of the start of the URL (position of the word dog + 4 spaces) to get the length.

In your HTML to text output, you need to check what the HTML looks like, and search for a word before the URL starts, and a word after the URL starts, and count the exact amount of spaces to reach the URL. You can then put those words and counts into your code.

More generally, when you have a complicated problem that you need to troubleshoot, you can break it down into steps. For example. Rather than putting that big mess of code into a single block, you can make each chunk of the code in its own compose, and then one final compose to bring them all together - that way when you run it you can see what information each bit is giving out, or where it is failing, and experiment from there to discover what is wrong.

Comment: Hi @Cazzym Hawkins, thanks truly for your thorough answer and it really helped me solve the problem! I finally got the outputs of the URL at Compose ^ ^. Sadly the flow still fails at HTTP step with HTML status code 307 given. I assume maybe the server of the report's provider just doesn't allow using MS Flow > <  But sincere thanks to you, truly!

Comment: @PPPPPPPPisces that's a code for a URL redirect. That means that the server is telling you "actually, that's not the final location of the thing you're asking for, let me get you the final URL and send you over".

If in the flow run you can see how to access URL that the failed HTTP spits out, you can take that in the following step and use it to make a 2nd HTTP request to the new, true location. You'll just have to change the action setting to Run After -> Failed, that way the second part will run even after the first one throws a complaint because it can't get anything from the URL.